# max number virtual IP addresses per NIC

Tags: linux, networking, ip

How many virtual IP addresses are allowed to be added per network card? I am running a Linux OS.

Comment: Do you mean IPv6?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is "as many as you have have memory to support and IP addresses available". There is not a soft limit in the kernel that I am aware of.

[What is the Maximum Number of IPs that can be Assigned to a Given Computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/231656/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-ips-that-can-be-assigned-to-a-given-computer)

Comment: I've done over 2,000 before without a problem. I've read success reports up to 5,080 addresses. (And that was all that person needed.)