# Limit on IPs assigned to one interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

I have a unique application where I need to use many IPs on one server.
Will Ubuntu networking crash if I assign 2048 IPs to one eth0 interface?

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/328146/max-number-virtual-ip-addresses-per-nic

Answer (score 1):

No it will not, you can have as many as you want